# MSBuild for my UWP app fails with Error BG1004, Error MC1002 and Error BG1003

Tags: msbuild, uwp, azure-devops

MSBuild for my UWP App fails with below errors:
1. Error BG1004: Target Type 'appcontainerexe' is not supported by this task.
2. Error MC1002: Library project file cannot specify ApplicationDefinition element.
3. Error BG1003: The project file contains a property value that is not valid.

I am using a private build agent running as a service over a VM because I needed an SDK which was not present on VSTS.

I am not able to understand any of the errors. The .csproj file specifies output type as AppContainerExe because thats needed to run a UWP app. The App.xaml has output type as ApplicationDefinition and again thats needed because it is an entry point.

On my VM where my private build agent runs, I have installed VS 2015. Do I need to install anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually caused by the "Universal Windows App Development Tools" isn't installed when install the Visual Studio.

[image]

Install it on the build agent and then try the build again.